# Restangular, setResponseInterceptor for a single request

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular with AngularJS, Can we set responseInterceptor for a single request, not for all requests?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this;

```
var BondRestangular = Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
  RestangularConfigurer.setResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what) {
    // do your thing
    return data;
  )};
});

BondRestangular.all('actions').getList();
```